# Jquery Even Odd number Increment Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check with below code... actually number is not getting increment

```js
var current = 0;
$("#categories-2 ul li").each(function() {
   if (current  == 0) {$('#categories-2 ul li').addClass('evenNum'); console.log("2");}
   
  else if (current  == 1) { $('#categories-2 ul li').addClass('oddNum'); console.log('1');}
   current++;
});
```

Comment: is it possible to provide html too ?

Comment: Thank you DRD help me with my queries )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more efficient way to do it using JS: http://jsfiddle.net/ou44wcwn/.  Overall, using `even` and `odd` in `:nth-of-type` or `:nth-child` pseudo-class is generally a better practice.

JS/jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul li").each(function(index, elem) {
        $(this).addClass(index % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd");    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to add classes if the li items are odd or even, right?

The proper way to check if something is even or odd is the modulo operator ( `%` ) that calculates the remainder of a divison. So %2===0 checks if something is even. If that evaluates to false then it is odd.

So you can do this:

```
var current = 0;
$("#categories-2 ul li").each(function() {
   if(current%2===0) $('#categories-2 ul li').addClass('evenNum');
   else $('#categories-2 ul li').addClass('oddNum');
   current++;
});
```

If you're trying to style even and odd list-items ('`<li></li>`') then you may be better off looking at the nth-child css3 technique:

The selector `#categories-2 ul li:nth-child(even)` will style all even list-items
and the `#categories-2 ul li:nth-child(odd)` will style all odd list-items.

Here's an article on how nth-child works: https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: If you found this helpful-- I believe this is what you are trying to do-- then please select this as the answer and upvote. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery, use it to the max

```
$("#categories-2 ul li").each(function() {
     console.log($(this).index());
   if ($(this).is(":even")) {$(this).addClass('evenNum');}
   else{
 $(this).addClass('oddNum');
}
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/b4r27xjh/)